# Set a maximum height for different sized images

Tags: java, android, imageview, frame

I have been struggling for a while with the following problem. I have an activity with - let's be simple - only one ImageView. This `imageview` can contain different sized images - the URL of the image is added by `Bundle` from a previous activity. What I would like to achieve is to set a maximum height for the images which cannot be exceeded by any kind of image and also keeps the aspect ratio. 
One of the problem is that I am not sure which `scaleType` I should use, and I also tried to add the `setMaxHeight` parameter but doesnt seem to have an effect. If the height of the image does not reach the maximum height it should be obiously smaller. The width is always `fill_parent` in my case, the issue is with the height. How could you achieve this?

As a start I did put the imageview into a FrameLayout (later I need to put stuff on the imageview).

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/my_stub" />


        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what is your problem with `setMaxHeight`?

Comment: It works if an image's height is bigger than the maxHeight. But if an image's has e.g. 2:1 aspect ratio (and the height is still bigger than the maxHeight) then the image is scaled down until the full width appears. I need to have an image zoomed/cropped until it reaches the maxHeight if its width is bigger than the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

```
adjustViewBounds="false"
setScaleType="center"
layout_height="whatever height you want it to be"
```

You may should set a minimum width programatically to handle small images

everything else seems fine

Comment: still doesnt zooms in but shows the whole picture with full width. I need to force it to reach the maxHeight

Comment: if set match_parent for the width, the view (in that case the image) can not be wider than its parent, if you want it to use max height and allowing the zoom, set width: wrap_content, it will zoom in until it reach the full height and uncheck :adjustViewbounds and scale :center

Comment: Almost good! But for larger portrait images where the height is bigger than the maxHeight, it doesnt have an effect and appears in full height.

Comment: In that case you need to handle it programaticaly.
get the image height by .getHeight(), and if it is bigger, set adjustviewbound to true programatically

Comment: you will have to convert the image to a bitmap first. I will put the code once I'm done with mine

Comment: You're awesome, its working now! Another little question: if I wanted to cover this imageview with an opaque black (e.g. 50%) View placing it onto the imageview, how should I set that height? Since now the imageview is zoomed and scaled down but it thinks that the imageview height is the one without scaled.

Comment: If i understand well, you want to place a view on top of the image kind of like when you want to put a description of the image, in that case int opaque_black_height = imageView.getHeight()/2; where imageView is the view displaying the image.
Note thatthe imageView is not scaled, it has just a maximum height so no matter how big the image is, the imageView.getHeight()/2; will always be half the height of the view